# R. How to calculate level based on number in one dataframe?

Tags: r, apply

This is probably a super easy and basic question but I can't find answer. I have a data frame with some nums. And I need to add another column to that database with strings that would represent this data. What I mean, for example:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Bad |
| 20 | Good |
| 15 | Bad |
| 35 | Good |

"Bad" and "Good" is intervals, for example, "Bad" is 0-20 and "Good" is 20+.
How do I do that with R? I think I need to use apply func.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(num = c(10, 20, 15, 35))
data
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>     num
#>   <dbl>
#> 1    10
#> 2    20
#> 3    15
#> 4    35

data %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(num <= 20, "Bad", "Good"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>     num result
#>   <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1    10 Bad   
#> 2    20 Bad   
#> 3    15 Bad   
#> 4    35 Good
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Or using base R:

```
data <- data.frame(num = c(10, 20, 15, 35))
data$result <- ifelse(data$num <= 20, "Bad", "Good")
```

If you have more than two levels (e.g. low, medium, and high), you can also use the function `cut`. There is also the function `dplyr::case_when` if the rules are more complex.

Comment: Thanks! And what I'll have three levels of gradation? Good, Normal and Bad? Will that work?

Comment: Yes, it can be anything you like. just change the text after `~` in case_when

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate` and `case_when`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(v1 <= 20 ~ "Bad",
                              v1 > 20 ~ "Good"))
```

Output:

```
  v1 status
1 10    Bad
2 20    Bad
3 15    Bad
4 35   Good
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(10,20,15,35))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut`.

```
x <- c(10, 20, 15, 35)
cut(x, c(0,20, Inf), c("Bad", "Good"), right=FALSE)
#[1] Bad  Good Bad  Good
```

What can easy be extended to more levels of gradation.

```
cut(x, c(0, 12, 25, Inf), c("Bad", "Normal", "Good"), right=FALSE)
#[1] Bad    Normal Normal Good
```

Or subset a vector.

```
c("Bad", "Good")[1+(x>=20)]
#[1] "Bad"  "Good" "Bad"  "Good"
```

Or using `findInterval`.

```
c("Bad", "Normal", "Good")[1 + findInterval(x, c(12, 25))]
#[1] "Bad"    "Normal" "Normal" "Good"
```